# symfony 6 deserializer returns null

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization

I have a problem with symfony deserializer. I am getting null for all fields. Code exemple bellow

```
    $data = file_get_contents('file.xml');
    $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $deserializer = $serializer->deserialize($data, Item::class, 'xml',['disable_type_enforcement'=> 'true']);
```

Entity looks as ususal:
[image]

[image]

Items tag is closed[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your xml file contains an array of Item elements, not a single object, you need to set the appropriate type when deserializing, i.e. replace `Item::class` with `App\Entity\Item[]`, this way you can get an array of objects .

Xml example (letter case sensitive)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <name>Test Name 1</name>
        <price>125</price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Test Name 2</name>
        <price>154</price>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Deserialization method

```
public function index(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer)
{ 
    $data = file_get_contents('../public/item.xml');
    $data =  (new XmlEncoder())->decode($data,'json');
    $deserialize = $serializer->deserialize(json_encode($data['Item']),'App\Entity\Item[]','json');
    
    // do something
}
```